# Are there any good GUI tools for configuring Apache on linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, graphical-user-interface

I have been having trouble trying to get apache working nicely on Fedora 10, and would really like to have a GUI to configure it all.  I have tried using the .conf file, but it doesn't seem to work - I have set the server root directory to show access to all, but it seems that every folder still needs a .htaccess file (and these don't even all work).  I have tried using `system-config-httpd` from in the fedora repository, but some of the changes that I have made using that have prevented apache from starting, so I don't really want to use that anymore.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/files/webmin/webmin-1.480-1.noarch.rpm

rpm -U webmin-1.480-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: Any idea why it isn't in the repos? NB - would vote up but I don't have the rep to do so :(

Comment: Just installed it and it works great!

Comment: I really don't know how they decide what is in the repos by default.

Answer (score 1):

cPanel (and "WHM") have always worked well for me.  It has EasyApache3 which takes away lots of the pain of configuring and building Apache (installing modules, building and configuring PHP, and more in a few clicks).

http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/